# How can I select the first day of a every month in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @from_date DATETIME, 
        @Monthnos  INT 

SET @From_Date='2016-04-01' 
SET @Monthnos=1 

SELECT dmcode, 
       CASE 
         WHEN entitystatus IN ( 'Active' ) 
              AND CONVERT(DATE, codedate, 103) BETWEEN Dateadd(dd, Datediff(dd, 
                                                                   Datepart(dd, 
                                                       Dateadd(m, monthnos, 
                                                       @from_date)), 1), 
                  Dateadd(m, monthnos, @from_date)) 
                                                       AND 
                  Dateadd(dd, Datediff(dd, 
                              Datepart( 
                              dd, 
                  Dateadd(m, monthnos, 
                  @from_date)), 0), 
                                                       Dateadd 
                                                       (m, monthnos, @from_date) 
                  ) THEN 
         Sum(agentpartyid) 
       END AS ActiveCount, 
       CASE 
         WHEN entitystatus IN ( 'Inactive', 'Suspend' ) 
              AND CONVERT(DATE, codedate, 103) = Dateadd(dd, Datediff(dd, 
                                                             Datepart(dd, 
                                                             Dateadd(m, monthnos 
                                                             , 
                                                             @from_date)), 0), 
                  Dateadd(m, monthnos, @from_date)) 
       THEN Sum(agentpartyid) 
       END AS InActiveCount 
FROM   cms_v_agency_dump_master AD WITH (nolock) 
       INNER JOIN #branch_mom BM WITH (nolock) 
               ON AD.dmcode = BM.dm_code 
GROUP  BY dmcode, 
          entitystatus, 
          CONVERT(DATE, codedate, 103), 
          monthnos
```

I have the above mentioned query i want a count of Agents who is active and their coding date between first_day and last day of every month and if agent is inactive or suspended then their coding date equal to last day of every month.
where Monthnos is our financial month i.e (if month is april then monthnos=1 ,april then monthnos=2 and so on..).
So, how can i achieve this in sql..???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query only between the 1st day of every month, assuming your DATETIME field is `monthnos`, you can simply add:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(month, monthnos, GETDATE())=1
```

Comment: I used case statement in select statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your going to get the first day of the month the employee starts. Make sure to exchange the GETDATE() for the date field in your table that designates the start date. You can copy and paste this as-is to get an idea of how the output will look.

```
select dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,dateadd(m,0,getdate())),0)
```

This one will give you the last date of the month the employee was terminated. As before replace GETDATE() with the date field in your table.

```
select dateadd(s,-1,dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,getdate())+1,0))
```

These are useful because of the fact they are in the SELECT statement they will not interfere with conditions you set on pulling data. They just convert the way the dates look.

Here is what your query will look like:

```
   SELECT dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,dateadd(m,0,GETDATE())),0) AS StartDate,
       dateadd(s,-1,dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,GETDATE())+1,0)) AS EndDate

FROM   cms_v_agency_dump_master AD WITH (nolock) 
       INNER JOIN #branch_mom BM WITH (nolock) 
               ON AD.dmcode = BM.dm_code
GROUP BY ....
```

You shouldn't need the Declare and Set anymore. I'm not familiar enough with your DB to fill in the GROUP BY but you can take it from here. Hope this helps!!